# Let's get MathOverflow's "Citation Helper" here, too!

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, citation, editor

MathOverflow recently received a brand-new toy: a [citation helper](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2583/new-feature-citation-helper) that adds a new button to the post editor to allow references to journal articles (and more?) to be added to posts quicker and easier.

[image]

Of course we need this, too.  Who agrees with me?

Comment: Yes, I agree. I'm still using Scott Morrison's original plugin for this website, but it would be nice if it will be implemented here as well.

Comment: @AsafKaragila To be precise, the script is jointly authored by Scott Morrison and Manish Goregaokar aka Manishearth ([source](https://github.com/semorrison/SE-CitationHelper/blob/master/citationhelper.user.js)).

Comment: @Norman Hugh Mann: Yes. Right.

Comment: Could you post an example of such a citation?

Answer (score 4):

example citation

*G. A. Edgar*, [**Transseries for beginners**](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.rae/1285160533), *Real Anal. Exchange* **35** (2010), no. 2, 253--309.

(I searched using the title, and it found the reference for me.)

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Absolutely. There are already [39 posts](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/637434/which-posts-have-included-citations) that use citations without the helper, so I see no reason not to include it here too.

Please let me know if any problems arise as a result. (Though I don't anticipate any.)

Comment: Interesting to look at those 39 posts. Some of them use the cite tag for other things (e.g. wrapping the source of a quote, for some reason); but of those which use it to actually cite papers, all but three are actually my use of the MathOverflow citation feature (and to some extent the Greasemonkey script that predated it).

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Hopefully we'll see even more people use citations properly in the future. One of the things we wanted to be sure of when installing the new script was that it would work with any Stack Exchange site that might cite mathematical papers. It's wonderful that we can reuse the work done for MathOverflow here.

Comment: Yes. I am happy to have taken part of the zbMATH revision, and I'm happy that pushing it forward on MO made it reach to other sites as well.