# Button for citation helper in the editor

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, citation, editor

The icon for citation helper in the editor Window used to be hyperlink in a speech bubble, see here: [Let's get MathOverflow's “Citation Helper” here, too!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/22008)

At the moment the icon is a letter B - very similar to bold. Could this be corrected, please?

[image: screenshot of editor's icons]

This was reported also in MathOverflow Meta: [Icon for citation helper](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/4470).

Comment: In the comments on [MathOverflow Meta discussion](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4470/icon-for-citation-helper), it was suggested that posting bug report also here might be useful. If the problem is confirmed by other users, this bug report might be used to test the new way of escalating issues: [Community and Moderator guidelines for escalating issues via new response process (March 2020)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345032).

Comment: Martin, I see this bug too. It's exactly the same as the 1st B on the LHS

Comment: I was not aware that math.stack had this feature. I've just tested how it works.